# Why would an abstract interface ever be used?

Tags: java, minecraft

Just come across this code inside the game 'Minecraft'

```
public abstract interface CompleteVersion
extends Version
{
    public abstract String getId();

    public abstract ReleaseType getType();

    public abstract Date getUpdatedTime();

    public abstract Date getReleaseTime();

    public abstract int getMinimumLauncherVersion();

    public abstract boolean appliesToCurrentEnvironment();

    public abstract String getIncompatibilityReason();

    public abstract boolean isSynced();

    public abstract void setSynced(boolean paramBoolean);
```

}

There is also a couple public final abstract interfaces as well, although I won't bother copying them over.
In what situation is this ever a good idea?

Comment: Interfaces are inherently abstract -- this is a redundant specifier

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces are abstract by definition.  The `abstract` keyword means that the methods inside the interface have no implementation.  But this behavior is already mandatory for an interface.  Therefore the `abstract` keyword is redundant when used with interfaces.

Comment: Is there no situation as to why you would ever use this?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use it or don't use...it is enforced automatically by the Java language specification.